# Raised object vs. Subordinate subject (I didn't want Kim mistreating my cat)

Tags: gerunds, subordinate-clauses, nonfinite-verbs

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*  (Page 1204) says:

> A crucial difference between gerund-participials and *to*-infinitivals is that a non-genitive NP can function as subject of the former but not of the latter unless *for* is present:
>
> [13] i *What I resented was Kim mistreating my cat*.
>
> ii **What I intended was Kim to interview both candidates*.
>
> iii *What I intended was for Kim to interview both candidates*.

CGEL continues on the next page:

> We have no reason, therefore, to analyse the NP following *resent* as a raised object--instead we take it as subordinate subject, so that the syntactic structure matches the semantics:
>
> [14] i *I caught **Kim** mistreating my cat.* [matrix argument; matrix object]
>
> ii *I resented **Kim** mistreating my cat.* [not matrix argument; subordinate subject]

In a nutshell, CGEL treats ***Kim*** not as a raised object but as the syntactic subject of the subordinate clause *mistreating my cat* in [14ii], because the corresponding *what*-cleft construction works in [13i].

Then, see these examples:

> (1) *I didn't want **Kim** mistreating my cat*.
>
> (2) *What I didn't want was **Kim** mistreating my cat*.

I think (2) as well as (1) works. Does that mean that ***Kim*** is not a raised object but subordinate subject in (1)?